# Why are there no exchange traded options on 3x leveraged ETNs

Tags: options, etn, leveraged-etf, sec

Since these would help me manage risk in my personal financial portfolio, why are there no exchange traded options on 3x leveraged ETNs?

Is there a prohibition that the SEC is perpetuating? Is there an agreement amongst exchanges not to trade them? If the SEC is approving/disapproving these particular products, what authority is that based on?

I've anecdotally heard "too much leverage" before, but there are ways to get more leverage than options would provide and it also isn't law (although the SEC has historically unparalled discretion over how ETFs and ETNs operate), so any insight into this would be great

Comment: Many leveraged ETFs do. Such as SPXL. 3X S&P, with listed options. I'm still studying what can be gained from the strange decay issues these 3X exhibit over time, the daily leverage that can't exist for a year due to volatility.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer yes, but as you noted, I am curious about the ETNs

Comment: Understood, but you tagged and referenced ETFs as well. Is your question why is it available on leveraged ETFs but not ETNs?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I actually created the leveraged-etn and sec tag for this question. the ETF tags were the only ones available. There are a lot of products that attempt to offer 3x exposure which are only available as ETNs with no options.

Comment: Ok. Do I have it right now? In general, 3X ETFs have options, 3X ETNs do not?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer yes

Comment: Can I request you to elaborate why you want options on leveraged ETF as opposed to just the option on the ETF?

Comment: @Victor123 the premiums would be much much greater on the leveraged etf, for starters. If one were selling, then they would be able to collect a great premium. If one were long the option they would still be able to hedge their equity position. The usual reasons.

Comment: Thank you very much. Never thought that premium would be greater on a leveraged etf even if it (underlying) costs the same as the unleveraged etf

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger yes, I am aware they are different. ETNs are debt objects, "notes", and I was wondering what this distinction has to do with being optionable

Comment: did a little searching at CBOE.com, and it seems at least some ETN's have options (vxx).  My guess is that CBOE doesn't think enough volume will occur on the particular ETN in question to warrant them running the quotes system.

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger this is about some fairly liquid 3x ETNs though

Comment: Could you provide some examples of specific ETNs?

Comment: @xirt since this question was asked 3 years ago, the SEC has put a lot of 3x products under scrutiny and many were subsequently delisted, so, no.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that exchanges don't perceive there to be enough trading interest to warrant the set up and running cost. I guess you would have to ask them...